# What kind of curvature does a cylinder have?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

[Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) is a kind of like an infinitesimal curvature. For example, all points of a sphere has positive Gaussian curvature. [Angular defect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_defect) is kind of like a "point charge" of curvature. For example a cube has positive angular defect at its 6 corners.

So what do you call the curvature on the two circles of a cylinder? It has positive infinite gaussian curvature, but 0 angular defect.

Note: The cylinder is closed, i.e. has a top and bottom (like [this](https://www.varsitytutors.com/assets/vt-hotmath-legacy/hotmath_help/topics/volume-of-a-cylinder/cylinder1.gif)).

Comment: I don't understand how you come up with "infinite gaussian curvature"? The cylinder is locally isometric to the plane and thus has $0$ guassian curvature.

Comment: Gauss curvature is not infinitesmal, but is a property at any point on a smooth surface or manifold.Also angular defect is not a property at a point but for a curvilinear spherical triangle derived from vertices of a triangle. I suggest you could consider deletion for now and re-post a while after study of spherical trig, Gauss Bonnet thm, spherical excess etc.

Comment: @noctusraid I mean a cylinder with a top and bottom disk.

Comment: @Narasimham angular defect can also be defined at a point. That is the angular defect I'm referring to, not the triangle one.

Comment: Your kind of definition of angular defect does not figure in Gauss Bonnet thm.

Comment: @Narasimham: Why should a question be closed just because in your personal repertoire there is no immediate answer?

Comment: East sir, it was not clear to me what OP was asking, was only trying to help  out in case OP needed time to collect some input for a clearer  question.I feel actually the question concerns more on topology rather than differerntial geometry, but of course from my side no pretences to wider coverages than needed.

Comment: @PyRulez To me the question sounds more like .. for a closed cylinder with  flat topped caps.. *where from comes integral curvature $\int\int K dA = 4 \pi$  when everywhere $K=0$?*

Comment: Should it not be from GB thm reckoned properly?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a definite answer, just a collection of ideas, before they close down the question.

This is an interesting question. It refers to a finite cylinder $C$ closed by two top and bottom disks. The resulting "surface" $S:=\partial C$ is homeomorphic to  $S^2$. On the smooth parts of $S$ the Gaussian curvature is $0$. On the other hand by the Gauss-Bonnet theorem the total curvature of $S$ is $4\pi$. In the case of a convex polyhedron $P$ this total curvature is concentrated in a $\delta$-function like way in the vertices of $P$. In the case of $S$ it is concentrated in the two circular "edges" of $S$. The total tangent turning along these edges is $4\pi$. A proper definition of the "Gaussian curvature density" would therefore lead to the value $1$ per unit of tangent turning along the "edges". But the angle between the tangent planes along the edges should also play a rôle. A limiting approach could be considering the parallel bodies $C_\epsilon$, $\epsilon\to0+$,  of our cylinder. These have a smooth boundary, which consists  of toroidal pieces of surface along the edges of $C$  whose Gaussian curvature we have under control.

I'm sure this problem has been dealt with somewhere. Unfortunately the people who might know about it have been excluded from sharing their knowledge with us.